# Debug Pyspark on EMR using Pycharm

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm, amazon-emr

Does anyone have experience with debugging Pyspark that runs on AWS EMR using Pycharm?

I couldn't find any good guides or existing threads regrading this one.

I know how to debug Scala-Spark with Intellij against EMR but I have no experince with doing this with Python.

I am aware of being able to connect to remote server using ssh (EMR Master) and maybe with Professional edition I can use the remote deployment feature to run my spark job using Pycharm but I'm not sure if it will work and I want to know if anyone has tried it, before I will go with Pycharm Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I got to debug Pyspark on EMR as I wanted to.
Please look at this Medium blog post that describes how to do so:

https://medium.com/explorium-ai/debugging-pyspark-with-pycharm-and-aws-emr-d50f90077c92

It describes how to use Pycharm Pro - remote deployment feature in order to debug your pyspark program.